# Unit setup for a real world modeling

Tags: transforms, scene, units

I have a problem with blender. Iam currently working for a architect and they send me models from archicad, in real world scale. The blender shows meters but when export they see it as millimeters. I have to manually set up the units to 0.001 so the scale and to the big object be visible. The camera clip start and end has to be set up to huge numbers to actually see the whole object (building) and it has some visual errors with such a number. Whi the scene cant be always the same, and just to change millimeters to meters and work in such a scale.Anyone has experience with this problem?